# how to remove a string having special characters from a file using php

Tags: php, regex

I have this file.txt  file

```
domain.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
@*.domain6.com
domain4.com
domain5.com
```

and I need to remove

```
@*.domain6.com
```

using php , I am using this code

```
$file="file.txt";
file_put_contents($file, preg_replace("/^\@\*\.domain6\.com$/","",file_get_contents($file)));
```

but it does not work , anyone can explain me why it does not work and how to remove this
row ?

Comment: You forgot the `/m` flag.

Comment: I tried it now, does not work too

Comment: _What_ doesn't work? Is your file empty? Does the wrong line get replaced?

Comment: Aha, so I bet you need `"/^\h*@\*\.domain6\.com$/mu"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```php
$file="file.txt";
$rx = '/^\h*@\*\.domain6\.com\h*$/mu';
file_put_contents($file, preg_replace($rx,"",file_get_contents($file)));
```

*Details*:

- `mu` - `m` makes `^` match start of any line and `$` end of any line
- `^` - start of a line
- `\h*` - any zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `@\*\.domain6\.com` - `@*.domain6.com` string
- `\h*` - any zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Plq8Y/4).

**NOTE**: If you have trouble with escaping special chars, in PHP, you can use

```php
$rx = '/^\h*\Q@*.domain6.com\E\h*$/mu';
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Plq8Y/3). All chars between `\Q` and `\E` are treated as literal chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the text using the following

```
$file = "file.txt";
file_put_contents($file, str_replace("@*.domain6.com","",file_get_contents($file)));
```

Let me know if it works.

It's working for me.

**UPDATED**

If you want to replace line-wise with line starting

```
file_put_contents($file, implode("",array_map(function($line) { return strpos($line,"@*.domain6.com") === 0 ? str_replace("@*.domain6.com","",$line) : $line; },file($file))));
```

OR simply use this

```
file_put_contents($file, str_replace("\n@*.domain6.com","",file_get_contents($file)));
```

Comment: I need to check that the string @*.domain6.com is at the start of the row using ^. If I use ^ it does not work.

Comment: Answer updated, Hope it Satisfies your need.